# connecting two monitors - Lenovo Ideapad y-700

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, lenovo-laptop

I recently bought a new laptop (Lenvno ideapad Y-700 80NV001KIV) and would like to connect it to 2 monitors.

I bought a docking station and connected the two monitors to it and then connected the docking station to the laptop.

unfortunately only one screen is displaying and it seems that the other screen is not even getting detected by the computer (the other screen is connected via hdmi cable to the docking station).

I tried several solutions and couldn't make it to work, can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, HDMI does not support daisy-chaining a second external display regardless of the use of a hub?  I believe you'd need DP1.2 to support that.

Answer (score 0):

You might look up the manual for the docking station, you should add the model of the docking station to the post.  It might not support that configuration (some docking stations do, some don't).  Or it maybe a docking station driver issue.  If it is Windows causing the issue you probably want to make sure under the display setting that You are "Extending these displays" on both monitors.  Like below.  To get here right click on an empty part of your desktop --> Display Setting --> Display in the left side menu and you should see something similar to below.  Finally, and this maybe silly, you might have to have the laptop closed for it to show on both external displays.
[image: System Display Settings Win 10 x64]